# iOS 7 UIViewController (with navigation bar) doesn't inset UIScrollView

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uiscrollview, ios7

I've got a UINavigationController with a UIViewController showing a navigation bar.

I've specifically set `[self setAutomaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets:YES];`, though this should be `YES` by default anyway.

I add a UIScrollView:

```
self.scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
[self.view addSubview:self.scrollView];
```

However, the UIScrollView's contentInset is `{0, 0, 0, 0}`, so I am wondering why it doesn't inherit the content inset from the view controller as the documentation states it would.

If I add subviews to the scroll view and set their Y to be `self.scrollView.contentInset.top` they don't appear below the navigation bar, which is what I am expected.

What am I doing wrong here? It works fine if you start out with a `UITableViewController` since it correctly inherits the `contentInset` from the view controller.

Thanks!

Comment: The contentInset (and contentOffset) adjustment will only be seen after the view is on screen. Can you confirm that they are still not being set in `viewDidAppear` or later?

Comment: Ah, that might be there issue here, that I am trying to set it in `loadView`

Comment: Ah, definitely wouldn't recommend doing more in `loadView` than creating and assigning something to `self.view`.

Comment: I moved this to `viewDidAppear:` and the UIScrollView still does not inherit the contentInset. It's still 0 from the top, even after the view has loaded.

Comment: Is your scrollView the main view? `setAutomaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets:` only applies if the main view is a scrollView. i.e. if your scroll view is hidden in a hierarchy then the insets will not change.

Comment: @jefflcy87 Wait, so I have to set self.view = scrollView?

Comment: I'm running into the same problem with a UIWebView.  At least from the .xib, it seems the issue is related to objects in the window that are above the uiwebview - i.e., like a UILabel.  If the label is there, then the insets aren't set properly - if it's not, then it's fine.

Comment: @runmad My comment previously may have been misleading. What I mean is your view hierarchy must be like this.  
View (self.view)  
--->ScrollView  
--->Other views  
  
If you have anything in between self.view and your scrollView `[setAutomaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets:]` will not work i.e.  
  
View  
-->Other views (UIButton, UILabel, UIView etc)  
-->ScrollView

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
self.view = self.scrollView;
```

Works fine for me.
Tested with UIWebview:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.view = self.webView;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It adjusts the scroll view bounds, not the content insets.

Comment: No. I want content to appear underneath the navigation bar, etc. You do not get this if you adjust the bounds.

Comment: Why the -1?  If you look at how the scrollView is affected when setAutomaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets:YES, you will see that the bounds are changed depending on the presences of a navigation bar and/or status bar.  For example, hide the status bar, and you'll see the bounds.origin.y changed by 20.  If it is NO, then the bounds are not changed.

Comment: The content inside UIScrollView doesn't scroll beyond the bounds. But it scrolls beyond the inset. I want content to scroll beyond the bounds.